# Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator don't get resource ID when android rom is Root

Tags: android, root

device info:
Galaxy Nexus(I9250)
4.2.2(JDQ39)
ROM:yakju

use adb command:
adb shell
$shell@android:/$
su
shell@android:/ #

when i use the tool named "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator",i want to get some apps resource -ID,but not get it;

when i creat avd,and use adb command
adb shell
root@android:/#
this way can get resource -id

real devices root,and avd root ,what is the different?

Answer (score 1):

4.3 and 4.4  can get resource -id,

Comment: @keen_rong your answer is currently under `low quality posts` review. Could you please edit and give some explanation to the question?